# Sending arguments to server but stay in current page

Tags: html

I'm running a simple python webserver on a raspberry pi that has a control.html
file that has an argument called led that should turn off or on a led.

The file has two buttons when clicked send the arguments to my server
and the led functions as it should.

How can I make it that when i click one of the buttons the arguments
are sent but the control.html is still displayed with the buttons?

The problem is that now when i click one of the buttons the action is
performed but a blank page is shown . It requires me to use the back
button on my browser to get my control.html back.

### control.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://192.168.2.78:8123/control.html?led=on';"   value="LED ON" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://192.168.2.78:8123/control.html?led=off';"   value="LED OFF" />
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of things AJAX was developed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function ledOn() { 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open("GET", "control.html?led=on", true)
    xhttp.send()
}

function ledOff() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open("GET", "control.html?led=off", true)
    xhttp.send()
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="ledOn()" value="LED ON" />
<input type="button" onclick="ledOff()" value="LED OFF" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to accomplish this is to throw jQuery in there and use an AJAX request like so: (this is untested)

jQuery probably adds more overhead than you need, but this is what I've got off the top of my head (and it sounds like it's not terribly important one way or the other for this).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //When the ledOn button is clicked, send a GET request to the on url
            $('#ledOn').click(function() {
                $.get('http://192.168.2.78:8123/control.html?led=on');
            });
            //When the ledOff button is clicked, send a GET request to the off url
            $('#ledOff').click(function() {
                $.get('http://192.168.2.78:8123/control.html?led=off');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="ledOn"  value="LED ON" />
    <input type="button" id="ledOff" value="LED OFF" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A toggle button would even be nicer :)

Comment: We'd have to know the state when the page loads. Depends if there's a way to fetch the status or not.

Comment: I would like to add the possibility later to reflect the state off the led in the control.html webpage.